# How do you edit records in a form that diplays records from two joined tables (Firebird - Lazarus)

Tags: firebird, freepascal, lazarus

I'm using Lazarus and a Firebird database to display several Forms. The datasource related query_1 joins two, sometimes three tables, and the data is shown in TDBEdit displays.

I need to place two buttons on forms: MODIFY and SAVE for the users. If data was only one table MODIFY would basically call Query_1. Edit, and SAVE would ApplyUpdates. With the joined tables in the query ApplyUpdates would give an error, but thought I could have the SAVE call a query_2 to select the record in one table (and later the corresponding one in the othery -all in the same transaction) and Edit the modified field taking the value from the TDBEdit.Text or the modified dataset’s fields, but this does not work because Lazarus/Firebirs does not let the user write into the TDBEdit of the joined table even though they are not ReadOnly.

I could instead use simple TEdits , populating them from Qry_1 fields to display the data and make changes, and then use the modified texts to edit the corresponding fields, but this will require a lot of changes as well as programing to keep the user from introducing garbage, and seems not to be the best solution.

I believe I am complicating something that should be more "standard" and simple but have not found other solutions. Would appreciate somebody pointing me to the right “normal” practice.

Comment: joined datasets are read-only, cause they can come from many differnet sources at once, for example from stored procedures, which are not editable. I think you have to find a component or a property like Delphi's `TUpdateSQL` and manually write proper Insert/Update/Delete scrpipts. Another similar approach in Delphi would be using in-memory caching datasets - MIDAS aka DataSnap aka TClientDataSet/TDataProvider - but i am not sure if LCL has something of a kind

Comment: Thanks,
I will be researching Delphi´s TUpdateSQL and caching datasets to see what I can learn/find.